Is format directly not supported in typebox
I have started using typebox recently in my nodejs project.
Most of the formats and validations are not working and compiling properly
Like Type.Strict() -> does not enforce any strict schema like zod
I tried to add formats for email check that also not recognised
Do we have to add ajv additionally for these formats but then ajv-formats library is depricated and https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv-formats-draft2019 is being used now
I tried to go without ajv as per doc and added format but its not working.
This is as per doc:
You can pass Json Schema options on the last argument of any given type. Option hints specific to each type are provided for convenience.

// String must be an email
const T = Type.String({                              // const T = {
  format: 'email'                                    //   type: 'string',
})                                                   //   format: 'email'
                                                     // }

// Number must be a multiple of 2
const T = Type.Number({                              // const T = {
  multipleOf: 2                                      //  type: 'number',
})                                                   //  multipleOf: 2
                                                     // }

// Array must have at least 5 integer values
const T = Type.Array(Type.Integer(), {               // const T = {
  minItems: 5                                        //   type: 'array',
})                                                   //   minItems: 5,
                                                     //   items: {
                                                     //     type: 'integer'
                                                     //   }
                                                     // }


Validation :
import { Type, Static } from '@sinclair/typebox';
import { TypeCompiler } from '@sinclair/typebox/compiler';

export const userBSchema = Type.Object({
  id: Type.String(),
  username: Type.String(),
  age: Type.Number({
    multipleOf: 2
  }),
  firstName: Type.String(),
  isActive: Type.Boolean(),
  email: Type.String({ format: 'email' }),
  address: Type.Object({
    street: Type.String(),
    city: Type.String(),
    state: Type.String(),
    zipCode: Type.String()
  })
});

export const createManyUserBRequestBodySchema = Type.Pick(
  userBSchema,
  ['username', 'age', 'firstName', 'email', 'address'],
  {
    additionalProperties: false
  }
);

export const createManyUserBRequestSchema = Type.Object({
  body: Type.Array(createManyUserBRequestBodySchema)
});
export type CreateManyUserBRequestType = Static<typeof createManyUserBRequestSchema>;


Usage
 async myFUnction(input) => {
        try {
          const C = TypeCompiler.Compile(createManyUserBRequestSchema);

          const isValid = C.Check(input.request);
          if (isValid) {
            const output = await this.createManyUserUseCase.execute(input.request.body);
            return {
              message: 'Many User Api Processed Successfully',
              result: output
            };
          }
          const all = [...C.Errors(input.request)];
          throw new AppError({
            name: ApplicationErrorType.VALIDATION_ERROR,
            message: JSON.stringify(
              all.map((item) => {
                return `error is ${item.message}`;
              })
            ),
            cause: all
          });
        } catch (err) {
          return {
            result: Result.fail<Error>(err)
          };
        }
      }

And my input is
Input Json
[
    {
        "username": "alpha_user",
        "age": 2,
        "firstName": "ALpha",
        "email": "alpha@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "street": "S",
            "city": "AMX",
            "state": "UK",
            "zipCode": "54367"
        }
    },
    {
        "username": "beta",
        "age": 22,
        "firstName": "beta",
        "email": "beta@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "street": "kotavilla",
            "city": "BETA",
            "state": "UK",
            "zipCode": "54367"
        }
    },
    {
        "username": "gamma",
        "age": 24,
        "firstName": "gamma",
        "email": "gamma@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "street": "kota2villa",
            "city": "GAMMA",
            "state": "UK",
            "zipCode": "54367"
        }
    }
]

This is error:
"message": "[\"error is Unknown format 'email'\",\"error is Unknown format 'email'\",\"error is Unknown format 'email'\"]",
The email format is correct still not recognized

The format keyword does not perform validation by default. It has always been descriptive/annotative.
I'm not sure about the system that you're using, though. There may be a configuration that enables format validation.

Just wanted to know if TypeCompiler captures this format, other part is captured as error but format
this  const C = TypeCompiler.Compile(createManyUserBRequestSchema); will capture this  and configuration as in ?If I use ajv then there is no need for this typecompiler for valdiation check, I wanted to know can this be achieved without use of ajv or not, its document state the format but never mentioned it will work or not in typecompiler

I suggesting asking the maintainers of TypeCompiler by raising an issue.
